# Manually creating and editing Kubernetes objects

Tags: kubernetes

Most Kubernetes objects can be created with `kubectl create`, but if you need e.g. a `DaemonSet` — you're out of luck.

On top of that, the objects being created through `kubectl` can only be customized minimally (e.g. `kubectl create deployment` allows you to only specify the image to run and nothing else).

So, considering that Kubernetes actually expects you to either edit a minimally configured object with `kubectl edit` to suit your needs or write a spec from scratch and then use `kubectl apply` to apply it, how does one figure out all possible keywords and their meanings to properly describe the object they need?

I expected to find something similar to [Docker Compose file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/), but when looking at [DaemonSet docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/), I found only a single example spec that doesn't even explain most of it's keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spec of the resources in `.yaml` file that you can run `kubectl apply -f` on is described in [Kubernetes API reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/).

Considering DaemonSet, its `spec` is described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/daemon-set-v1/). It's `template` is actually the same as in Pod resource.